# Ninject Multicasting

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, ninject

I want to bind multiple implementations of a service and have all of them called at once:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel.Bind<IBreakfast>.To<Spam>();
kernel.Bind<IBreakfast>.To<Eggs>();
kernel.Bind<IBreakfast>.To<MoreSpam>();

kernel.Get<IBreakfast>().Eat();   // call Eat method on all three bound implementations
```

Ninject doesn't like that, and will throw an exception about having multiple bindings.  Is there a way I can get around that error, and have all the implementations called?

Also, the `Bind<>` calls can be in different projects which may or may not be loaded at run-time, so creating a single implementation to call them won't work.  This is part of a plug-in architecture for an ASP.NET MVC 3 web site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use constructor injection and have a `List<IBreakfast>` parameter, then Ninject will construct a list using all your bindings. You can then call `Eat` on these instances.

You can use this pattern to get Ninject to create a list of your plugins for instance.

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<IBreakfast>().To<Eggs>();
        kernel.Bind<IBreakfast>().To<Spam>();
        kernel.Bind<IBreakfast>().To<MoreSpam>();

        var bling = kernel.Get<Bling>();
    }

    private class Bling
    {
        public Bling(List<IBreakfast> things)
        {
            things.ForEach(t => t.Eat());
        }
    }

    private interface IBreakfast
    {
        void Eat();
    }

    private class Ingrediant : IBreakfast
    {
        public void Eat(){Console.WriteLine(GetType().Name);}
    }

    private class Eggs : Ingrediant{}
    private class Spam : Ingrediant{}
    private class MoreSpam : Ingrediant { }
```

Output:

> Eggs
>   Spam
>   MoreSpam

Comment: I'll try this in the morning when I get to work, but won't Ninject throw an error on the second call to `Bind<>().To<>()`?

Comment: @MikeWyatt: No, multiple `Bind`s are fine. What's not fine is going a `Get<T>` that yields more than a `Single` item. If you want to do that, you can use `GetAll<T>` (or use the implicit batching up of multiple registrations via `List<T>`, `T[]` or `IEnumerable<T>` as suggested) (And people that post/code as tests don't ever post stuff that blows up!). Note that Ninject doesnt have any muchanismt to generate an implicit Composite to multicast the calls in the way you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind many concrete classes to once single interface, that's against DI rules.

What basically you want to do is, initialize couple of concrete instances and call their method.

You may want to check this out:

```
Bind<IBreakfast>.To<Spam>().Named("Spam");
Bind<IBreakfast>.To<Eggs>().Named("Eggs");
Bind<IBreakfast>.To<MoreSpam>().Named("MoreSpam");

var breakfastList = new List() { "Spam", "Eggs", "MoreSpam" };
breakfastList.ForEach(item => kernel.Get<IBreakfast>(item).Eat());
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's against DI rules. If your problem domain naturally fits there always being a potential one-to-many relationship between an interface and concrete classes, then that's fine. Decent IoC containers let you model this scenario. The OP's plugin scenario is one of these types of model.

Comment: This approach doesn't work with a plug-in architecture because, by definition, you don't know what plugins will be present.