# Ninject / IoC proper initialization of StandardKernel

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, ninject, ioc-container

I'm just getting started with IoC containers and have picked up Ninject to start with. I understand the principle of the separate modules you can incorporate into a Kernel. But I'm curious if I should have the first line below everywhere in my code where I'm about to ask for the concrete implementation of something from my service layer.

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new SimpleModule());
// example: getting my ContentService
IContentService contentService = kernel.Get<IContentService>();
```

If I have a class with 10 methods that use the ContentService should I really new up a Module and a Kernel in every method? Seems like a code smell. How do most developers handle this with Ninject? Are there any articles online that show the proper way to do this with the consumer class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, basically two ways of working with IoC: Dependency Injection (DI) and Service Location (SL).
When dealing with dependecy injection, you provide you dependencies from outside your classes. Generally, you do this by injecting (passing) your dependencies into the class constructor or by using setters. For example:

```
public class SomeClass {
        public ISomeDependency SomeDependency {get;set;} 

        public SomeClass(ISomeOtherDependecy someOtherDependency) {
           //...
        }
}
```

In this case, you COULD provide a ISomeDependency implementation through the property and you SHOULD provide ISomeOtherDependecy implementation through the constructor. Ninject support both ways.

The other way of doing (SL) allows you to request for your dependencies in the moment you need, for example:

```
public void DoSomeAction() {
   ISomeDependency someDependency = MyServiceLocatorImpl.GetInstance<ISomeDependence>()
}
```

If you plan to use the SL approach (or an hybrid one), you could use the [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) (Ninject [has support](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Changes-in-Ninject-2) for it) . It makes easy to switch our IoC engine later.

Comment: When you go down the route of using the Common Service Locator do you give up the Ninject List<> capabilities mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959709/ninject-multicasting

Comment: I'm not sure about that, as it depends on ninject's implementation of the interfaces needed by th Common Service Locator. It is worth testing.
Anyway, if my opnion count, don't use service location. It's easier (and readable) to write tests by injecting your dependencies (rather then asking for them when needed).

Comment: I'm leaning against it (SL). Just trying to wrap my head around how some projects ... like a simple WinForm app should work with DI.

Answer (score 3):

> If I have a class with 10 methods that use the ContentService should I
>   really new up a Module and a Kernel in every method?

No, you should have this class take `IContentService` as constructor parameter (since it depends on it inside its methods) and then ask the kernel to provide you the instance of this class. Your classes should know nothing about the DI container (Ninject in your case). They should never reference it.

Comment: So I'm trying to understand if you go the DI route instead of the SL route, you should only ever have one class that asks for a new Kernel? In a WinForm app does the mean the Program class would do this and you need to inject some master service into your MainForm (Form1) so that you could get to all your other services?

Comment: Or I guess from the UI layer or WCF Layer I could new up a Kernel during the initialization of that layer and then set a private class-level variable to hold the reference to the Kernel.